# DataTable TableName = DataView.ToTable("TableName") will not work

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

I am trying to make a copy of a DataTable with a different TableName.  I have used this in the past without issue and the code from the past works just fine today.  When i try using the exact same code the table will add to the DataSet but there is no data or column names.

```
DataView dv = dataSet.Tables["Traveler"].DefaultView;   /// the dataview is exactly like the datatable
DataTable Parts_Kit = dv.ToTable("Parts_Kit");          /// the new datatable has no data or columns
dataSet.Tables.Add("Parts_Kit");                        /// Parts_Kit is added to dataset but completly blank
```

I have dorked around with this for 4 hours now with no results.  What could i possibly be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the definition of `Add(string DataTable name)`, you are creating a new / blank table in dataSet that has nothing to do with the `DataTable Parts_Kit`.

As per [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTableCollection_Add_System_Data_DataTable_) as well, you want to use,

```
dataSet.Tables.Add(Parts_Kit); // without quotes around Parts_Kit.
```

This will add the table you created from view (`Parts_Kit`) to the `DataTableCollection`, `dataSet`. To Test this as well, you can print `Parts_Kit.TableName` to see if it is the correct "Parts_Kit" name (from `ToTable("Parts_Kit")` command).

Comment: Jawed, thanks for catching that.  sometimes the punctuation will get the best of me.  how i didn't catch that when reviewing my previous code is beside me.  Life is good again and pressing forward.  Such a rookie mistake.